# how to send jwt token correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular application I am trying to send a jwt token as a header in order to authorize my app for requests. But I am getting an error 500 because I am sending the jwt token in a wrong format, this is how I am sending right now:

```
Bearer {"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MDMxMTg0MH0.zWxESmFkM_nE8LEqIfFwSb-nEG593qaYnS1IFjd9qdYbOZJmMSXirfW3S68lQ0PBJcNop-OGtB6JJjtNJprDIQ"}
```

What I want is the following:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MDMxMTg0MH0.zWxESmFkM_nE8LEqIfFwSb-nEG593qaYnS1IFjd9qdYbOZJmMSXirfW3S68lQ0PBJcNop-OGtB6JJjtNJprDIQ
```

I tried the following but I am getting an undefined can not read property of trim error:

```
token.split(" ")[1].trim()
```

could someone help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my interceptor where I am trying to send the header:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!request.url || (request.url.startsWith('http') && !(environment.rootUrl && request.url.startsWith(environment.rootUrl)))) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    const token =
      localStorage.getItem('token') ||
      sessionStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
      console.log(token)
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.split(" ")[1].trim()
        },
      });

    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Added the method which saves the token:

```
 authenticateUser(login: LoginModel){
    this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler)
    return this.http.post(environment.rootUrl + 'api/authenticate', {
      username: login.username,
      password: login.password,
    }).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data))
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])

      }, error: (error) => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false
      }
    })
```

console.log:

```
{"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MDMxNzk0OH0.YACaabpkEWEkG6a65GspdLL9Ds50rQNBAou9f1X-mq2NMeSsNRZoabuMK3WcNAd_8t3q-yeDkNPYbMQkFD8B2g"}
  }
```

EDIT2:

console log of data:

```
{id_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiO…nSYP5PctcyXIQ_RuoaQQ72w5bf2YO943WoRhTQTER-y0LH6iw'}
```

Comment: What does the token variable contain? What is the output of `console.log(token)`?

Comment: If i just enter token it is like the first example and if I try to split it like I said i am trying it is undefined. But I do not know how to instantiate it

Comment: how are you saving you token variable? if you're sending your token like "Bearer {"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTY1MDMxMTg0MH0.zWxESmFkM_nE8LEqIfFwSb-nEG593qaYnS1IFjd9qdYbOZJmMSXirfW3S68lQ0PBJcNop-OGtB6JJjtNJprDIQ"}" but you're taking your token by using localStorage.getItem('token') ||
      sessionStorage.getItem('token'); So maybe your saving your token as an object in local storage. You better save as text, so when you get from localstorage or sessionStorage it'll takes just the text and not an object

Comment: Please answer my question, I asked what the console.log prints exactly. Also show us how you save your token like Jose asked. Looks like the localStorage item contains a serialized object instead of just the jwt token string.

Comment: I added it both the mtehod which saves the token and the console log output

Comment: Ok there's your problem, you're saving your token as an object and when you try to get it you don't use its property "id_token", so when saving you can use localStorage.setItem('token', data.id_token), or then you can get id_token from your object when localStorage.getItem

Comment: dont store JWT in localStorage, place it inside a HTTP only secure cookie, then you don't need faff with placing it in Bearer headers, implement Bearer header if you want to offer public apis

Comment: @JoséLourenço I tried what you said but data does not have the id_token at least I can not access it. I added the console log. And if I try to get id_token instead of token in from my localstorage I am getting an null

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I dd not quite understand what you meant to be honest. How do you mean it?

Answer (score 0):

If the API response sends it as a JSON Object then you will need to parse the JSON using

```
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.parse(data).id_token)
```

This will parse the incoming JSON response from the API and then get the id_token key.

However if the API response sends it as a string and NOT a JSON Object then you will get an error if you try to use JSON.parse() as it is not a valid JSON Object. Therefore you can just use

```
localStorage.setItem('token', data.id_token)
```

I dont know if your API returns a string or JSON object hence why i have provided both pieces of code.

You don't need to use token.split

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.split(" ")[1].trim()
```

You can just send the token as

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
```

Hope this solves the problem